# Conversion of Ethernet address to readable form?

Tags: c

```
struct ethernet_header
{
    u_char ether_dhost[ ETHER_ADDR_LEN];

    u_char ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];

    u_short ether_type;
};

for(i = 0;i <6; i++)
  printf("dest ether:%x",ethernet->ether_dhost);
```

How to print the Ethernet address in proper readable form with spaces after each byte? The o/p I get is in hex. Here Ethernet is the pointer to the structure `ethernet_header`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
char mac[6 * 2 + 5 + 1];

for(size_t i = 0, pos = 0; i < sizeof ethernet->ether_dhost; i++)
{
  if(i > 0)
   mac[pos++] = ':';
  sprintf(mac + pos, "%02x", (unsigned int) ethernet->ether_dhost[i] & 0xffu);
}
```

This also inserts colons between each byte, so the output will look like `DE:AD:BE:EF:BA:BE` which is how MAC addresses are commonly formatted for Ethernet.

Comment: If the type `u_char` is an `unsigned char`, it is likely to be promoted to `int`, but `%x` expects an `unsigned int` argument.

Comment: @caf: Thanks, that's true and a common problem. I've added both a cast and an explicit mask.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
    (unsigned)ethernet->ether_dhost[0],
    (unsigned)ethernet->ether_dhost[1],
    (unsigned)ethernet->ether_dhost[2],
    (unsigned)ethernet->ether_dhost[3],
    (unsigned)ethernet->ether_dhost[4],
    (unsigned)ethernet->ether_dhost[5]);
```

Comment: +1, more idiomatic than a loop (you can tell it's a MAC address at a quick glance).

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way would be to use ether_ntoa() which is available on just about any *nix operating system (available in net/ethernet.h). The following works quite well for me.

```
char *addr;
struct ether_addr host;

memcpy(&host, ethernet->ether_dhost, sizeof(host));
addr = ether_ntoa(&host);
```

Comment: It seems available in <netinet/ether.h> on Linux platforms.